# Docker engine failing to start after changing docker root directory

Tags: linux, docker, centos7, docker-engine

I just created a new partition on my Linux CentOs 7, and after that I changed my Docker Root Directory from /var/lib/docker to /data/docker.

In the 'docker.service' file I added the following config:

> ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -g /data/docker/ -H fd://
> --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

, after that I copied data from /var/lib/docker to my new directory /data/docker and then I do

> systemctl daemon-reload

and

> systemctl start docker

**BUT**

The service didn't start and I got this message:

> Warning: docker.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
>
> Process: 16925 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -g /data/docker/ -H fd://
> --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)  Main PID: 16925 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> Jun 29 23:26:37 linux.local systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
> Jun 29 23:26:37 linux.local systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
> Jun 29 23:26:37 linux.local systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
> Jun 29 23:26:37 linux.local systemd[1]: docker.service failed. Warning: docker.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload'to reload units.

My Linux version:

> Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core) CPE
> Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1160.90.1.el7.x86_64

Docker version:

> Client: Docker Engine - Community  Version:           24.0.2  API
> version:       1.43  Go version:        go1.20.4  Git commit:
> cb74dfc  Built:             Thu May 25 21:55:21 2023  OS/Arch:
> linux/amd64  Context:           default
>
> Server: Docker Engine - Community  Engine:   Version:          24.0.2
> API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)   Go version:
> go1.20.4   Git commit:       659604f   Built:            Thu May 25
> 21:54:24 2023   OS/Arch:          linux/amd64   Experimental:
> false  containerd:   Version:          1.6.21   GitCommit:
> 3dce8eb055cbb6872793272b4f20ed16117344f8  runc:   Version:
> 1.1.7   GitCommit:        v1.1.7-0-g860f061  docker-init:   Version:          0.19.0   GitCommit:        de40ad0

Does anyone have any idea about what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is really caused by the docker version that I'm using, but the docker version that I'm using doesn't recognize the option '-g' so the docker service doesn't know where the docker root directory is. After I checked the options known by 'dockerd' it turned out that the option that should be used was '--data-root', after I replaced -g' with '--data-root' the docker.service could run using the new root directory!